# QT 4 update, removing lots of libs

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde, qt

I get a message from Muon update module aksing to update QT 4. Thats fine, but it also want to remove LOTS of libs and programs (incl spotify, ksystemlog, krdc, krfb, kdepim-runtim, userconfig and many others that look important for my system (kubuntu 12.04) to function. Is it OK to let Muon remove all those packages??

Comment: I wonder if there is time saving way to overcome dependency issue about it. Personally in that situation I note down removed apps and reinstall them

Comment: You can also check what was removed in the package history. Do you get the same problem with `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: Do you have the Kubuntu experimental PPA enabled ?. There was an announcement: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2014-January/007856.html . The Kubuntu developers are asking feedback. I would make a complaint if the new Qt version want to remove lots of programs.

Comment: Thanks user26687, that was the problem. I've sent feedback to the developers.